# How to prevent open tracking in Gmail app on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, email, gmail

[Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en) says:

> Images will always appear in the Gmail app on your iPhone or iPad.

(This is different from opening Gmail in a browser on a computer, where I see settings that provide a choice: either "Always show images" or "Ask before showing images".)

**How can I read Gmail messages on my iOS devices if I want to ensure that my opens can't be tracked?**

P.S. The page linked above interestingly does *not* say:

> "Sometimes, senders may know whether you've opened an email that has an image."

even though the "Computer" tab on that page *does*. I can't tell whether this implies that Gmail opens are NOT trackable in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Sep 3, 2019, version: 6.0.190811, you can **Choose to be asked before external images are displayed automatically.**

> To enable this for new incoming messages, go to Settings > specific account > Images and select Ask before displaying external images.
>
> [image: Gmail - Email by Google - Version History]

**Gmail App - Account Settings - General**

> [image: Gmail Settings]

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: you can now prevent opening images automatically! See @vincentlee's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368184/151404).

---

The documentation linked, says:

> Images will always appear in the Gmail app on your iPhone or iPad.

Meaning **there is no way to block showing images when opening a new email in Gmail on iOS** - therefore you can't prevent tracking.

Here are some workarounds that I use:

1. Send the message to spam (using the checkbox), where images aren't loaded, view the email there, and then move it back to inbox (if desired) and archive/delete from there.
2. Use the built-in Mail app to specifically view the message which you don't want tracked and turn off "Load Remote Images" in "Settings" - "Mail".

---

*Issue with Mail: If you're concerned about tracking and want to leave remote image loading on, Gmail is better as you may archive/delete an email in Mail and automatically be taken to the next email - resulting in the images being loaded. Obviously you can always take actions from the inbox view in Mail, to remedy this issue.*

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [Outlook for iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596).  This mail client is mature, polished and has a key feature: a setting for users to toggle default image loading behavior:

[image]

---

#### Example of the control to load a message's images:

[image]

**Disclaimer**:  I am not affiliated with Microsoft or the Outlook engineering team in any way.

---